# What are the differences between these terms in kernel compilations

Tags: linux-kernel, make

How does the terms

make, make bzImage, make modules, make install, make modules_install relate to each other.

One kernel tutorial I saw used all make bzImage, make modules, make install, make modules_install commands to compile and install a new kernel. While another one used only make, make install and make modules_install commanads. So what are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over time, the Linux kernel compilation process has itself been developed further. It has become more complex, but also more streamlined. Run `make help` in the kernel source directory to see a list of all `make` targets and brief explanations of each.

With the current 5.x kernel series, the commands `make` and `make all` are equivalent: both of them will run an architecture-specific list of default targets.

On the x86 hardware architecture, the default list contains:

- `make vmlinux` to build the bare kernel (this is also automatically executed if you run `make bzImage`, as before you can make a compressed bootable kernel image file, you'll first need to make the thing you'll want to compress; the uncompressed version is also useful for certain kernel debugging tools.)
- `make modules` to build the kernel modules
- `make bzImage` to create the bootable compressed kernel image file.

All of the above can be executed as a regular user, without extra privileges.

On the other hand, `make install` will use either `~/bin/installkernel` or `/sbin/installkernel` if they exist. Your own `~/bin/installkernel` might include the use of `sudo` or similar where applicable, but the system `/sbin/installkernel` is typically written to expect that you already have root access.

Likewise, `make modules_install` will copy the modules of the new kernel version to `/lib/modules/<kernel_version>/` directory tree, so it will require root access to run successfully.

As the best practice is to avoid running any long and complicated processes (such as kernel compilation!) as root if there is no specific need, the current minimal kernel compilation process would be something like:

- configure kernel as a regular user
- run `make` or `make all` as a regular user
- run `sudo make modules_install` to install the kernel modules
- run `sudo make install` to install the actual kernel. I would recommend doing this last, since `/sbin/installkernel` may trigger other operations like automatic building of an initramfs file, and those other operations would be more successful if the new kernel modules are already in place.

But if you are doing kernel development and not just building a customized kernel for your own needs, you might want to use a more fine-grained process; for example, if you are developing a kernel module, you might want to run `make modules` as a separate step so you can more easily see if it fails because of an error you've made, and can get to fixing the error more quickly. After fixing the error, you will then be able to just skip to running `make modules` again, as the previous steps are already successfully done.

Likewise, a developer working with the early kernel start-up process might just want the bzImage for testing in another system (one with a tricky set of ACPI tables or whatever), and not care about the modules at all.